# Print more than one copy with pdfMake

Tags: typescript, pdfmake

I was using pdfMake for printing generated documents which works fine, but now I want to print more than one copy at a time. I have searched on the internet and on their documentation page with no luck, but a function as useful as being able to print more than once a document in the same call must had been implemented so clearly i'm doing something wrong.

My code:

```
function() {
// generation of the d content which i have already tested it generates the content right
const win = window.open('', "tempWinForPdf");
            pdfMake.createPdf(d).print({}, win);

            
            setTimeout(() => 
            {
                win.close();
            },
            this.printTime);
}
```

Print time is just a variable that contains in ms how many seconds should the window to wait before closing itself.

I have already tried things like

```
var dd = [d, d]
```

And then printing the dd which results in a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue I resolved my problem waiting until the tab created closes and then I called again the function:

```
async f(repeat: boolean) {
        ...
        const win = window.open('', "tempWinForPdf");
        pdfMake.createPdf(d).print({}, win);

        
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, this.printTime));
        win.close();
        if (repeat) {
            await this.f(false);
        }  
}
```